Dog keeps moving puppies
I just took in a stray about 9 weeks ago and she gave birth to puppies a week ago. I have a whelping box set up that is warm and quiet- she laid in there with them for the first 3-4 days. Now, she will not stop bringing them to me. Whether I am on the couch or in my bed, she brings the puppies to where I am. She is a small breed and the puppies are getting to be bigger than her mouth. She has dropped them and has also put them on the edge of the bed where they crawled off. I even put the whelping box in my bed last night and she still moved them to my arms. I'm anxious about their safety and I can't get her to stop moving them. Do you have any feedback? Thanks!

I'm no expert, but it seems like she trusts you, and maybe she needs a break. This sounds like a great opportunity to socialise them with people.

It sounds like she is nervous about their safety and wants you to take a turn watching them. Or maybe she just needs some time off. Or maybe she just wants to make sure they understand that you are part of her pack and trustworthy. Or all of the above; I doubt she has thought it out clearly beyond "bring them to Mom for a while".
